# How could i use javascript (probably jQuery) on a hyperlink to slide and fade the page away before moving on to the page the user clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if i have a link on my page, i want that link (and if this can be done easily through css or something, all links) to make the entire body slide off to the left as it fades to white. also, most of the pages that these links go to will be designed to do something else i don't have a clue how to do: Fade up from white, and slide on from the right. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Transitions are *so* web 1.0 :D

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably do it the way Github do with their Tree Slider. [They blogged about it](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/) you have a good reference

You'll have to notice that it is going to be a  little hard to apply it if your website is already done.

Comment: well my website is only just at the beginning so i'm fine =P